# How to match a substring at the end of a string in R?

Tags: r

I'm using grepl to detect if a string includes a substring. For example:

```
grepl("-B4","P6-B4")
```

which obviously returns True. Now I want to avoid cases which have characters after the "-B4" substring. For example I want to see False from the following:

```
grepl("-B4","P6-B41A")
```

As you can see the reason I want to avoid it is because 4 is different from 41 and I don't want to detect 41.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grepl("-B4$",c("P6-B41A", "P6-B4"))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems like the perfect time to use `endsWith()`.  It determines if a string ends with a specific character or series of characters.

```
endsWith(c("P6-B41A", "P6-B4"), "-B4")
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

And according to `help(endsWith)`, it's also more efficient than `grepl()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to extract the last 3 characters and do a `==`

```
substr(v1, nchar(v1)-2, nchar(v1)) == "-B4"
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("P6-B41A", "P6-B4")
```